# How to automate a spreadsheet so that changing a value in one cell allows that entire row to appear in a separate tab of the worksheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, automation

Say I have a spreadsheet, as shown below:

[image: Spreadsheet example]

Is there some kind of tool, add-in or formula, that would allow me to take all of the rows that are in 'July', and put them in a table in a separate tab:

[image]

In such a way that if I changed say 'COA' (the first row in the first picture) from January to July, it would automatically update the separate table to include this?

(Or at least be updateable with a click of a button or by refreshing)

My boss has asked me to see if this is possible, and I have no idea of how to go about it.

Thanks

Comment: [Is this what you are looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21473890/445425)

Comment: Possibly, unfortunately however when I do it the Microsoft Query box says "This data source contains no visible tables"

Comment: You have two choices: make your data into a Table, or from Options, enable System Tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.
In order to extract multiple items from a list you can use the INDEX function with SMALL to create an array formula.

Try the formula below. It assumes that the first column is A and column F contains the months.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$F$300,SMALL(IF(($F$2:$F$300="July"),ROW($A$2:$F$300)-1),ROW(1:1)),1),"")
```

IMPORTANT: use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER when entering this formula to make it an array formula. You then need to auto fill down to get all the July records. This formula pulls data from column 1 (that's the last 1 in the formula). If your code in column 1 is unique to each row you can use a VLOOKUP to get the other columns.  If it's not then you can copy the formula to the next column. And change the 1 at the end to 2..3 etc.

Instead of putting July in the formula you can reference a cell that contains July and then duplicate the sheet and change the cell to August or simply change the cell whenever you like to see data for different months.

It's not an easy formula to follow but it does work.

Comment: That was quite useful. I've got it to find the first 'July' value, and used VLOOKUP to fill out the rest of the row. However I'm struggling to auto fill the formula down to get the rest of 'july'. When I do so I keep getting the same value. Any ideas to what is going wrong?

Comment: Solved it - the end of the formula ROW($1:1)),1),"") shouldn't have a $ sign

Comment: Apologies, I was trying to make the columns fixed and I made the rows fixed by mistake.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a Pivot table with all the columns expect month in the rows section, using tabular view, no subtotals, and repeat item labels. Then put month in the filter section. Then you can update the pivot table by right click refresh or by clicking the refresh all on the data tab